# default activity not found after upgrading intelij

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I had previously been doing fine but after I decided to update intelij to version 13 when I try to build my app it says default activity not found. In my androidmanifest.xml by each activity name

```
<activity
       android:name="start"
```

it  says unable to resolve symbol "start" for example. what can I try to get it to build properly?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be something like `android:name=".Start"` or `android:name="my.package.Start"` where `Start` inherits `Activity`?

Comment: clean and rebuild usually resolves this.

Comment: i tried that a few times and had no luck